# How do I open a file inside a package in the Source Packages of Netbeans?

Tags: java, file-handling

I'm relatively new to Java and Netbeans. What I want to do is to topen this Word document file that's inside the package "bloodreports.resources".
[Location of the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrM0t.png)

The reason I'm trying to open it from there specifically is because I think once the runnable JAR file is built, it won't matter where and on which machine I run the JAR file; The resource will always be there.

Is there a better way to do it? Am I wrong?

I've been trying to get this to work for past hour... any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried something along the lines of the following code:

```
public class WordDocumentHandler {
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String path = "/resources/bloodreportformat.docx";
        File file = new File(path);
        if(file.exists()){
            System.out.println("Exists");
        }
    }
}
```

The word "Exists" never gets printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Resources are not files. Use `getResource()` or `getResourceAsURL()`. Neither [tag:netbeans], [tag:windows], nor even (God help us) [tag:computer-science] has anything to do with it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a resource in Netbeans. As @user207421 said, you can't access resources the way you've done, because resources aren't files. You need to use the `getResource()` function to solve your problem. Modified code:

```
public class WordDocumentHandler {
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String resource_path = "/resources/bloodreportformat.docx";
        
        URL resource_url = WordDocumentHandler.class.getResource(resource_path); //Use this function

        //Check if the file exists
        if (resource_url != null) {
            System.out.println("Exists");
            //Other code
        }
    }    
    
}
```

The `getResource()` function returns a URL of the resource you're trying to access. Once you have the URL, you can access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

When working with resources in a Java project, the file paths are handled differently compared to typical file paths.

In Java, when you're accessing a file within your JAR (or within the resources folder), you can't directly treat it as a File object as you would with regular file paths on your file system. Instead, you need to use the `getResource()` method to access resources from within your JAR file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "/bloodreports/resources/bloodreportformat.docx";
    
    // Get the URL of the resource
    URL url = WordDocumentHandler.class.getResource(path);
    
    if (url != null) {
        System.out.println("Exists");
        // Now you can use this URL to access the resource
        // For example, if you want to create a File object, you can do:
        File file = new File(url.getFile());
        // Do whatever operations you need with this file
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not exist");
    }
}
```